# How to create a relative linux crontab in bash: NOW (date) + 24 hrs

Tags: linux, bash, cron, relative-date

I need a way to create an entry on the crontab that executes a script only once in 24h.

Steps:

- Run a bash script to configure a crontab to run a script in 24h (with command `date`?). This will run only ONCE 24 hs after .
- 24h later the script runs.
- At the end of the script execution, the crontab must be left clean. This means to remove the entry from the crontab. I don´t want to pollute the crontab with deprecated entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to pollute the crontab, you can use "at"
e.g.

```
at now + 24 hours
```

now you will get "at>" prompt, and you'll be able to enter the code which will be executed in 24 hours

You can also execute a shell script using:

```
at -f shell_script now + 24 hours
```

additional info can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(Unix)

and here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/scheduling.html